# Error en consulta a la base de datos! desde PHP a MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

He tenido problema al realizar esta consulta a la base da datos.La variable de consulta ($resultado1) dice 'Error en el query database'.

```
<?php     
$con=mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('Error en la conexion');        
$username=$_POST['nombre'];  
$password=$_POST['passa'];  
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `Username`=\'$username\' and `Password`=\'$password\'";  
$resultado1=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database');
mysqli_close ($con);  
echo 'Si esta registrado';   
?>
```

Comment: Hola Angel, ¿cuál **inserción** de datos? La consulta que muestras es un `SELECT`,  no un `INSERT`... ¿no será otro el código problemático?

Comment: Perdon. La consulta no se ha podido realzar. No se que este mal

Comment: @ÂngelDâvídBermëo cual inserción de datos, Por favor podrias actualizar tu pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Imprime un mensaje de error específico, puede que estés escribiendo mal la consulta: **`$resultado1=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database: '.mysqli_error($con);`** Sé claro en el planteamiento. Dices que te tira el mensaje: *no se ha podido realizar la consulta con exito*, pero ese mensaje no aparece en el código que compartes, en el cual tienes el mensaje: *Error en el query database*... Eso hace que tu pregunta sea confusa.

Comment: Ya actualize la pregunta. Soy nuevo en la comunidad y no se plantear muy bien las preguntas. Perdón por la confusion. ¿Si me comprendes ahora o no?

Comment: Angel, ¿probaste usando `$resultado1` como te indico en mi anterior comentario?: **`$resultado1=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database: '.mysqli_error($con));`** (me faltó un paréntesis). ¿Qué error da poniéndolo así?

Comment: Ya, faltaba un paréntesis de cierre. Ponlo así: **`$resultado1=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database: '.mysqli_error($con));`** y escribe un comentario del mensaje que arroja.

Comment: Me arroja este mensaje: Error en el query database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\'angelcrak07\' and `Password`=\'davidbermeo07\'' at line 1

Comment: @ÂngelDâvídBermëo que version de php estas usando ?

Comment: Ves, la consulta estaba mal escrita. **Quita esto \ en la consulta**.

Comment: A Cedano. Me aparece esto : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$resultado1' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\freatico\procesar3.php on line 6

Comment: Pon el código como indico en mi respuesta, aquí no podía ponértelo en comentarios porque tu consulta usa la comilla de identificación, que interfiere aquí en los comentarios e impide que se vea correctamente lo que te quiero decir.

Comment: A Cedano. Yo quiero crear una condicion pero no se como se haria. La condicion es que si la consulta es correcta me rediriga una pagina y si no muestre un mensaje de error. Me entiendes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escribe tu consulta así simplemente:

```
<?php     
$con=mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('Error en la conexion');        
$username=$_POST['nombre'];  
$password=$_POST['passa'];  

/*Modificamos la consulta porque solo interesa saber si hay datos, por eso ponemos COUNT*/
$sql ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `usuarios` WHERE `Username`='$username' and `Password`='$password'";  
$resultado1=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Error en el query database' .mysqli_error($con));
/*Verificamos si encontró registros*/
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado1) > 0 ){
    /*Liberamos recursos*/
    mysqli_free_result($resultado1);
    mysqli_close ($con);  
    /*
       *Aquí rediriges, poniendo la url que quieres en lugar de lo que hay en http://www.example.com/
       *OJO: cuando se usa header no debe salir nada por pantalla antes de él
       *en el flujo de código que le corresponde
    */

    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

}else{

      echo 'NO esta registrado';
}


?>
```

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD DEL CÓDIGO:** La consulta usada en este código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL. No se quiso
>   profundizar en el tema debido a que se alejaba mucho del problema
>   original planteado y debido también a que el OP ha manifestado tener
>   poco conocimiento sobre PHP. No obstante dejo esta nota para advertir
>   sobre el grave riesgo de ejecutar consultas que concatenen valores
>   provenientes del exterior. Se recomienda también al OP aprender en
>   cuanto sea posible el uso de consultas preparadas como una solución
>   eficaz al riesgo antes indicado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Pero oye tu sabes que funcion php puedo utilizar para que en caso de que el usuario este registrado. Es decir la consulta sea correcta me rediriga a una pagina especifica?

Comment: @ÂngelDâvídBermëo se suele usar `header` ([ver enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)). Pero eso sería motivo de otra pregunta. Una vez realizada la consulta deberías verificar que la misma encontró datos y entonces hacer la redirección con `header`. También considera dar seguridad a tu código aplicando consultas preparadas. Editaré la respuesta haciéndola apta para redirección.

Comment: Ok. Espero la respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: @ÂngelDâvídBermëo si te sirvio la solucion del Buen A. Cedano PF coloca u check a su respuesta, asi ayudarias a otros que en caso busquen la mismo ya sepan de donde guiarse en la solución.
Gracias.

Comment: A. Cedano. Podrias colaborarme diciendo de que forma podria hacer la redireccion. Es que para ser sincero se muy poco de PHP. Te lo agradeceria

Comment: @ÂngelDâvídBermëo el buen A.Cedano te dejo un enlace como se realiza el re direccionamiento.
Aveces es bueno primero intentar luego si ves que ya no puedes pedir ayuda.
todos pasamos por eso esfuérzate tu puedes.

Comment: Ok Pierro, Lo hare!

Comment: Muchas Gracias A. Cedano. Me gusta tu forma de explicar, soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion y espero aprender muchas cosas nuevas. Tienes algun medio para contactarte en caso de que requiera algun consejo tuyo?

Comment: @ÂngelDâvídBermëo me alegra de que te haya servido. El medio mejor para contactarme es aquí mismo. El sitio ideal para aprender es este pues aquí, según el lenguaje o herramienta que sea, hay gente mucho más capaz que yo, que siempre te dará las mejores respuestas. Y en los casos complicados podrás tener varios puntos de vista y optar por la mejor solución. Además muchas de las respuestas dadas apelan a experiencias parecidas con el mismo problema, lo cual es otra ventaja añadida. En definitiva, en Stackoverflow estás en el sitio indicado y te aseguro que aprenderás mucho aquí.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda. Bueno cualquier pregunta la hare aqui. Buen dia

Answer (score 1):

Espero que te ayude hermano ,  un ejemplo simple para su select que estas realizando con php mysql.

De igual manera revisa la pagina oficial de php mysqli.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla de hacer una consulta y moderna es con el metodo prepare statments, es mas sencillo y facil. si te interesa conectarte asi;

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$db = "myDbname";
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", 'root', '');
$conexion = $conexion->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla WHERE id = 2 AND nombre = 'jose'");
$conexion->execute();
?>
```